# Converting character string to numeric value in user defined function R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function that will take an input of character strings "mm/did/yyyy" and return an output vector in numeric form the month, day and year. I essentially want to combine this new function with the weekday() function created below to ultimately return the day of the week the input character string corresponds with.

```
weekday<-function(q,r,s)
{ (if(q>= 3)
 m<-(q-2)
else
m<-(q+10))
k<-r
 c<-floor(s/100)
(if(q>=3)
y<-s%%100
else
y<-(s%%100)-1)
 f<-(floor((2.6*m)-0.2)+k+y+floor(y/4)+floor(c/4)-(2*c))%%7
if(f==0){return("Sunday")}
   else 
if(f==1){return("Monday")}
 else
 if(f==2){return("Tuesday")}
 else
 if(f==3){return("Wednesday")}
 else
  if(f==4){return("Thursday")}
 else
  if(f==5){return("Friday")}
else
  if(f==6){return("Saturday")}}
```

I tried using something along the lines of type.convert but this isn't producing the desired output. Any help would be great thanks!

```
 dateconvert<-function("q/r/s")
  {
    type.convert(dateconvert(), na.strings = )

    weekday(convertedanswer)
    Return (weekday)


 }
```

Comment: R has functions to convert character string to POSIX or datetime format then you can get either months, weekdays, days, year, or time from that datetime format. Why dont you use it?

Comment: Oddly, there is a plural version of your user built function that is included in base R: `?weekdays`.

Answer (score 1):

The lubridate package is great for this! You can use `lubridate::mdy()` to convert a date in the "mm/dd/yyyy" formate you mentioned, and then `lubridate::week()` to get the week.

```
lubridate::week(lubridate::mdy("10/05/2017"))
#> 5
```

If you want the day itself, rather than the numeric output, you can use

```
lubridate::wday(lubridate::mdy("10/05/2017"),
                label = TRUE)
#> [1] Thurs
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried lubridate package?

```
input <- "12/30/2017"

# change into as.date format
inputdate <- strptime(input, "%m/%d/%Y")

library("lubridate")
day(inputdate)
# [1] 30
month(inputdate)
# [1] 12
year(inputdate)
# [1] 2017
```

It seems like a roundabout way to get to the day of week though. You should try using wday() that comes with lubridate package.

```
wday(inputdate, label=T)
# [1] Sat
# Levels: Sun < Mon < Tues < Wed < Thurs < Fri < Sat. 
# as a Ordered factor (Sunday is first)

wday(inputdate)
# [1] 7 
# wday returns the day of the week as a decimal number (01-07, Sunday is 1) or an .
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively without package:

```
date = "06/10/2017"
POSIXdate = as.POSIXlt(date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
strftime(POSIXdate, "%A")
#Friday

# Or if you  like one-liner
strftime(as.POSIXlt("dd/mm/yyyy", format= "%d/%m/%Y"), "%A")
```

Comment: Also `weekdays` in base R.

Comment: Is there any way to do this so that a function created newfunction<-("10/06/17") would produce the vector 10 06 17  ? Ideally I would like for this to happen, so that I can put this result into my weekday() function above.

Comment: Do you want to have input of character `d <- "10/06/17"` and output a vector of character `c("10" , "06", "17")`? If so: `strsplit("10/06/17", "/")[[1]]`.